# Using javascript to calculate form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a question on how to use javascript to calculate a form, but I can't seem to get it. Sorry if it's obvious but I'm new to scripting. Okay, so I have a form in html where you can select different options:

```js
if (((document.getElementById("age").value = "15")||(document.getElementById("gender").value = "male")||(document.getElementById("psy").value = "sedentary")))
  {
  return("2200cal");
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" placeholder="Enter age">
    <div class="row">
      <label for="gender">Gender</label>
      <select id="gender" name="gender">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select gender</option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="fname">Physical Activity</label>
    <select id="psy" name="psy">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select activity level</option>
      <option value="sedentary">SEDENTARY</option>
      <option value="mod">MOD. ACTIVE</option>
      <option value="active">ACTIVE</option>
    </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="if">
  </div>
```

and using it I wanted to use javascript to output a number based on this chart:
[output chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKjIb.png)

I tried using an equation to output a value by using if and then statements but it doesn't work, especially when it needs to find the result from all three variables together in the code.

Edit: fixed values but still not outputting anything.

Comment: What javascript have you actually tried? How did you listen for events, data, etc?

Comment: Does supplying unique values for the activity options (two have "make" as their value) solve the it-doesn't-work issue?

Comment: It would be preferable to have the chart transcribed and included in the post. That way others could run your code on your data and confirm the desired result.